# joomla 3 - how to disable front end login component?

Tags: php, joomla

I have searched and disabled joomla login module which hides login form in sidebar. But if I put

```
index.php/component/users
```

URL in address bar it still displays login form.

Is there any way to hide this login form ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent that by custom rewrite rules in `.htaccess` file.

```
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule index.php/component/users index.php [F]
```

or try creating hidden menu item (stacked in menu that doesn't have module so it's not shown on the page) and setting it's Access level to 'Special' but I'm not sure about this one.

Answer (score 0):

Before start website development process immediately after installation Joomla! or simply for preventing/blocking POST-data follow next steps.

Prevent all POST excluding /administrator folder in Joomla!
(file: /.htaccess):

```
####### Block front-end POST ##############
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/administrator [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
```

In "/admininstrator" folder - allow access by IP/DNS (file: /admininstrator/.htaccess):

```
##### Allow only developers/administrators ####    
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Where XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - admin IP-address.